# Session won't store attribute on PostBack when CheckBoxList is triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

My problem is that my List is not being retained during PostBack.
I am saving it into

```
Page.Session["mine"]
```

My design page consists of 2 controls( a Label and a CheckBoxList).

Because the number of items will change, I use a CheckBoxList instead of individual CheckBox controls and load each item dynamically in the page_load();

I am unsure of what it is called, either a member, attribute, or property. But I do have a variable that each method of the class are able to call on that holds the location of all selected items on the CheckBoxList.

```
Private List<int> locCheck = new List<int>();
```

When the OnSelectedIndexChanged() is triggered, the locCheck is renewed and stored in Session

```
locCheck = new List<int>();
int num = 0;
foreach(ListItem li in CheckBoxList.Items)
{
    if(li.Selected)
       locCheck.Add(num);

    num++;
}

if(locCheck.Count == 0)   //for testing purpose
    locCheck.Add(1); //2nd item

Page.Session["mine"]=locCheck;
```

I want to keep the selected checks on PostBack, but it never happens. In Visual Studio I have no problem. But when I load to server, I am using mono, I get the following message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I have this in page_load

```
if(Page.IsPostBack)
{
   locCheck = new List<int>();
   locCheck = (List<int>) Page.Session["mine"];
   Label.Text = String.Format("Is PostBack {0}/{1}", locCheck.Count, CheckBoxList.Items.Count);
}
else
{
   Label.Text = String.Format("Is Not PostBack 0/{0}", CheckBoxList.Items.Count);
}
```

I know the problem is with this line because locCheck.Count never changes in Label.Text

```
locCheck =(List<int>) Page.Session["mine"];
```

I know I have to attach

```
if(Page.Session["mine"] != null)
```

But I don't believe it is currently necessarry. Due to testing purposes, it should always have locCheck with at least one element.

i couldn't find an answer, so i started from scratch. instead of checklists i use panels of checkboxes that turn invisible when not needed.

I am still uncertain about Sessions but I have found something strange.

For example:

```
 Session["mine"] = locCheck;   //where lockCheck has 4 elements
```

there are times that locCheck is set to null sometime between page_load to a button click. 
i have found that when this is so, debug back to a point where locCheck is not null and has correct element values. then perform following:

```
 Session["mine"] = locCheck;
```

and later on, you perform the following code in click event

```
 locCheck = new List<int>();
 locCheck = (List<int>) Session["mine"];

 //then make your update:
 locCheck[3] = 7;
 Session["mine"] = locCheck;
```

for some reason, if i don't do this both Session["mine"] and locCheck become null and data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
      locCheck = (List<int>) Page.Session["mine"].ToString();
```

why to use page.session when you can use only session.